# How to fix CLS-Compliant in autogenerated XSD code

Tags: vb.net, cls-compliant

We have a data set and one of the columns is a VB keyword.  The generated code automatically put an underscore in front of it for the property name in *.designer.vb.  This is giving a warning for CLS-Compliance.  Now we would like to remove warnings and turn warnings as errors on.  I know how to fix this normally, but if I do sooner or later someone will touch the designer, regenerate the code, and remove the fix.  I can't change the column name at this point, it's too late.  Is there a way around this dilemma?

Comment: I try to get rid of those underscores xor warnings too. For now I set the whole assembly as ClsCompliant(False).

Comment: I hate to do that, as at some point we may want to change languages or at least use some dll's in a c# project.  But that might be the best solution.